meta tags are not rendered on server side (SSR)
I have SSR Quasar app and
I am using Meta like this
HomePage.vue

<template>
 
  <p >
hello
</p>
 
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { preFetch } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import { useMeta } from 'quasar';
import { useHomeMediaStore } from 'src/stores/home-page';

defineOptions({
  preFetch: preFetch(async ({ store }) => {
    return useHomeMediaStore(store).getMedia()
  })
})
useMeta({
  title: 'I am cute website ',
})

the  problem is that meta is not available on the initial html .
and when I see page source I can't see 'I am cute website' for page title.
what is the problem ?
note :other SSR stuff works correctly for example data fetching and rendering is correctly is done on the server .
